# Is there a way to do this inside Memgraph with triggers?

Tags: triggers, graph-databases, memgraphdb

When calling a query module from a trigger statement, what I expected to get within a function was a state of the graph before the query changes occurred. However, this is not the case, and made changes are already visible in the graph state. I’ll write a dummy example of such behavior:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger ON CREATE
BEFORE COMMIT EXECUTE
CALL my_module.function(createdVertices, createdEdges) YIELD node, property
SET node.property = property;
```

Function **my_module.function** should execute after following statement:

```
MATCH (n {id: 19}), (m {id: 10}), (u {id: 14})
CREATE (n)-[new_edge_1:RELATION]->(m), (n)-[new_edge_2:RELATION]->(u)
```

In **my_module.function**, we’ll see a graph state with just created **new_edge_1** and **new_edge_2**. If our calculation depends on having incremental changes, where we need the state of graph before any changes occur, is there a way to do it inside Memgraph with triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that with the triggers. During a single transaction, the changes of each query are visible in the next query. Triggers basically execute their statements as a query that is part of that transaction (if the `BEFORE COMMIT` is used).
You could probably use the changed values and ignore edges that are created in that transaction.